# yadcf: possible to use mData from another column?

Tags: datatables, yadcf

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
$('#myTable').dataTable({
  "ajax" : myURL + "/GetTableData",
  "aoColumns" : {
    {sTitle: "ID", bVisible: false},
    ...
    {sTitle: "Full Name",
      mData: null,
      mRender: function (data, type, arrRowData) {
        return mergeName(arrRowData[3],arrRowData[4],arrRowData[5])
      }
    },
    ...
    {sTitle: "Column 10", mData: 14},
  },
  "aaSorting" : [ 0, 'desc']
}).yadcf([{ column_number: 10 }]);
```

The problem is, I have several columns with `bVisible: false` which are not displayed, plus custom-defined columns such as "Full Name" above. Because of this, the mData index does not correspond to the actual displayed column index. I want to display the filter for "Column 10" (which is really column 14 in the row data), but the data that it's trying to filter is from column index (mData) 10, not 14. How can I specify the display column and the actual data column separately - is this possible? The only workaround I found so far is to hardcode the filter choices and pass them to yadcf using `data: [...]`, but this approach is obviously suboptimal and only works in a limited number of scenarios.

Editing to add (maybe this is easier): how would I create a filter for the "Full Name" column so that the filter choices are correct? Right now it only shows the first name (`arrRowData[3]`) because it apparently assumes that the original row data IS the whole column. But the strange part is, the filter does work on the whole column - so if I select "John" from the dropdown, it finds both John Smith and Bill Johnson.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your filters inside a container `div` / `span` and point yadcf column definition with [filter_container_id](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/933e77c612bf33f68933cb4413b4c3650929ed51/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L108) or [filter_container_selector](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/933e77c612bf33f68933cb4413b4c3650929ed51/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L113) , you can place your container anywhere you want (including table header)

Comment: I think you miunderstood my question - I'm not asking about the location of the filter on the page. I'm saying that the filter is not using the right data, due to the way my datatable is structured. Basically, some of the columns, eg "Full Name" aren't in the actual data returned by the server, but are generated on the fly from other columns (firstName, lastName). Because of this, the column indices in the data don't correspond to the column numbers on the page, and yadcf is getting confused. Hope that explains it better.

Comment: please provide a simple test case jsfiddle/ etc